# Twig Naming Convention of Webforms

Tags: webforms, twig, drupal-8

I am using Drupal 8. I have a web form named `careers_application` (machine name). I need to create a twig template for it. I tried to use `webform-submission-form-careeers_application.html.twig`, but it doesn't make any sense to web form at all.

Answer (score 0):

Using hook_theme_suggestions_alter, you can create whatever template suggestions you like. *For example:*

```
function Yourtheme_theme_suggestions_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {

  if ($hook == 'form' & !empty($variables['element']['#id'])) {
    $suggestions[] = 'form__' . str_replace('-', '_', $variables['element']['#id']);
  }
}
```

then you would create templates in your theme, such as

`form--user-register-form.html.twig`

or

`form--webform-submission-form-careeers-application.html.twig`

You can just use the suggestions, and it will do the rest, after you clear cache.
You can render your elements within the template.

*For example:*

```
<form{{ attributes }}>
  {{ element }}
</form>
```

#### Attachments:

- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/249856/custom-registration-twig-template
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220415/how-to-create-twig-template-files-in-drupal-8-for-customizing-user-login-profile